# How to deal with a stale head?

Tags: mercurial

I use `default` as the production branch, from which I create new branches when developing new features, which I ultimately merge into `default` (or close if this is a dead-end). I have trouble understanding the situation I am in. When trying to push the following repo, I get a "won't push several heads" message (from TortoiseHG)

[image]

My situation is the following:

- I want `390` to be the `default` (production) rev
- What happened between `387` and `388` was, retrospectively, a mistake. I should not have merged into default as the changes were not good enough. I will work on it later, but right now I do not want to deal with it, nor want it to mess with `390`. Is that the other head TortoiseHG is complaining about?

I do not want to force anything (been there, done that, suffered) so what is the appropriate action in such a case?

Comment: If you don't want it, can't you strip out those changesets, if they are as you say, merges? If you have done work you want to keep (just not deal with it now) on changesets 387/388 then you're in a different position.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: yes, I  want to keep them and work on them later (in a branch)

Comment: Another solution is to first clone or copy the local repository for safekeeping, then strip out those changesets and then push. This way you have a local copy of the mistake changesets for future peruse/use, but you don't need to deal with them until you're ready.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: good idea, this is what I ended up doing. Can you please copy/paste this into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that is often overlooked with distributed version control is that there are a lot more places to have repositories than simply "local" and "remote".

You can have many local repositories, having different changes, for different sub-projects, states, experiments, etc.

So one way to do this would be simply clone or copy the local repository so that now you have two local repositories. In the one you've been using all along you would now simply strip out the changesets you feel were a bad experiment. This gets rid of those changesets *in that repository* but you still have a copy in the other local clone. Now you should be able to continue pushing from your repository since you've effectively gotten rid of the extra head(s).

A different way would be to make a new local clone from the remote repository, then pushing only the changesets you want to keep from your original local clone into the new local clone, and then switch to using the new local clone going forward.

The end result would be the same, but the method getting there is different so depending on what is easiest you now have two choices.